# Can someone explain the creation and evolution of mankind as per our Sanatan Dharma (starting from the first Maanvantar)?

Tags: bhagavata-purana

I just read in quora that the Shrimad Bhagavatam gives information regarding all the kings since birth of the 1st Manu, his entire lineage, genealogy, the different continents and where Shri Vishnu is worshipped in what form. Since I haven't read the Puranas, I wish to know the entire account described in our great texts

Comment: Your question is broad. Also, what do you mean by "creation and evolution of mankind"?

Comment: Sanatana Dharma DOES NOT believe in evolution.

Comment: First of all according to hinduism man did not evolute. Secondly, there is a large number of youtube videos and websites which explain this. So this question can be closed.

Comment: full list is not given in scriptures only 7th manu's generalogy is elaborately described.. you may refer 9th canto .. how creation happened in the beginning , first manu, u may refer 10th chapter of 3rd canto of bhagavatam